# Proving that a ball of radius s is contained in a ball of radius r

Tags: vector-analysis

I need to prove this for my vector calculus class: $\forall \vec{x}\in \mathbb{R}^n$, define $B_{r}(\vec{x}) = \left\{\vec{y}\in \mathbb{R}^n\mid\left |\vec{y}-\vec{x}\right|<r\right\}$. Prove that $\forall r>0$ if $\vec{y}\in B_{r}(\vec{x})$, then $B_{s}(\vec{y})\subset B_{r}(\vec{x})$ where $s=r-\left \|\vec{x}-\vec{y}  \right \|$

I have more or less a visual representation of why this is true but I have no idea where to start my proof.

Thanks in advance for your answers,

IsaacM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows from the triangle inequality: Fix $z\in B_s(y)$, then $\| x-z\|=\| x-y+y-z\|\leq \| x-y\| +\| y-z\|$, and now use the definition of $s$.

Comment: Ohhh ok now I see thank you very much !!!

Comment: @IsaacM You should probably accept this answer.